# Как сгенерить токен в php?

Tags: php

Пишу API для онлайн-игры. Требуется сгенерировать токен игрока из 30 знаков (только цифры и английские буквы). Как это сделать правильно и быстро?

Comment: Google: "php generate random string fixed length", первая ссылка: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444877/generating-a-unique-random-string-of-a-certain-length-and-restrictions-in-php

Comment: @Rou1997, стремно то как. Спасибо

Comment: @Rou1997 Очень нехорошо. 1. Ссылка на материал на английском; 2. Отправка в гугл (https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2013/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%83%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b8/4844#4844). Если считаете что ответ уже есть - закрывайте как дубликат, если ответа по-русски нету (это важно) напишите перевод в ответ.

Comment: substr(md5(date('c') . rand(0, 100)), 0, 30); - типо так?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для начала как **не надо** делать. Не используйте для генерации `mt_rand()` или тем более `rand()` если вам нужны уникальные строки.

Токен, как правило, должен являться единственным и уникальным действительным ключем некоторой сессии авторизации. Проблем, с которыми вы можете столкнуться если выберете неправильный путь может быть несколько. Очевидными кажутся две из них:

1. Коллизия токенов - двум пользователям выдали одинаковые токены и они оба действуют от одной из учетных записей (явное нарушение разделения доступа);
2. Подбор токенов - злоумышленник угадывает систему формирования токенов и генерирует их получая доступ к авторизованным сессиям.

Например если в качестве токена выберем шестнадцатеричное число длиной 32 разряда - возможное их количество будет 16<sup>32</sup>. Это достаточно большое число, но чтобы случайно выбрать один из них нужно иметь источник случаных чисел, емкость которого превышает это количество.

`rand()` и `mt_rand()` (с версии PHP7.1 это одна и та же функция) выдают псевдослучайное значение из одной и той-же последовательности. Как правило количество чисел в этой последовательности равно 2<sup>31</sup>. Соответственно большинство комбинаций токенов не будут использованы и вероятность коллизии будет достаточно высокой. Пример проблемы можно почитать в [статье](https://habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/274253/) (пример не касается PHP, но проблема та же).

Идеологически более правильный подход - чтение исходной "энтропии" из `/dev/random` или `/dev/urandom`. Эти устройства можно назвать генераторами истинно случайных чисел и вышеупомянутых ограничений там нет. Об их работе можно почитать по-русски например [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/273147/) или по-английски `man 4 random`. Их конечно же нету в Windows, но я надеюсь вы не станете хостить проект на PHP в Windows (для этой оси есть более подходящая платформа). Для теста можно сделать и заглушку на `mt_rand()`.

Еще более надежный вариант `random_bytes()` (но он есть только начиная с PHP7) <del>или `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` (5.3+)</del>
Как подсказывает @Мелкий для более ранних версий есть внешние библиотеки, например https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat

Чтобы получить нужные вам символы, можно:

1. перевести исходную строку байт из системы счисления 256 в систему счисления с нужным вам алфавитом. Этот вариант не потеряет характеристики распределения исходной строки, но немного сложнее в реализации;
2. перевести грубым сопоставлением 1байт - 1символ. Допустим для вашего варианта (цифры и буквы) можно брать остаток от деления каждого байта на 36 (это количество символов в вашем алфавите) и по полученному индексу брать символ из набора допустимых (это может быть строка из цифр и букв, или пара `if`'ов). При этом варианте вероятность появления разных символов будет неравномерной, но это может оказаться не важно;
3. отказаться от варианта цифры и **все** английские буквы и оставить только [0-9a-f] - то есть просто перевести строку в шестнадцатеричный вид. Также сохранятся характеристики "случайности", но это несколько противоречит вашим исходным условиям.

Comment: `только цифры и английские буквы` как получить? :)

Comment: @Visman а это уже задача перевода строки из одного алфавита в другой :) Думаете нужно опубликовать решение?

Comment: `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` - использовать нельзя. Там ряд ошибок, что делает его не PRNG. Надо использовать именно random_bytes, есть userspace реализация для 5.2-5.6 https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat через libsodium, напрямую чтением urandom или через mcrypt.

Comment: @Мелкий Не знал. Хорошее дополнение

Comment: упс, про deprecated openssl я всё-таки наврал, то был mcrypt. Но openssl_random_pseudo_bytes реализован с ошибками, тут не наврал. https://habrahabr.ru/post/277779/

Comment: `mt_rand` юзаю... Я вообще учусь, денвер на смартфоне, php не 7, поэтому оставил такой вот шиткод до лучших времен

Comment: На смартфоне Android, поэтому я пишу на Linux :)

Comment: `Для начала как не надо делать. Не используйте для генерации mt_rand() или тем более rand().` - почему же не надо? Вероятность совпадения токена 30 символов, каждый каждый из символов  36 вариаций = 1/(36^30) степени, что практически неверноятно. Так зачем же извращаться? Может быть я что-то не понимаю -  но просто `надо` и `не надо` доверия не вызывают.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр Вы под утверждениями "не надо использовать mysql_query" уже написали комментарий? :)
`mt_rand()` (а с версии 7 и `rand()`) выдает всегда одну и ту же последовательность чисел длиной 2^31. Соответсвенно 36^30 комбинаций вы никак не получите, а получите на порядок меньше (то есть некоторых значений токенов не будет в принципе) - этой проблемы должно быть достаточно, чтобы не использовать `mt_rand()`

Comment: @tutankhamun вот это дельно спасибо, и правильнее было бы добавить к ответу.  Не все же знают тонкости rand - я не знаю, например. Люди то с вопросами и обращаются, чтобы им разъяснили, а не просто указывали как надо и как нет. На php.net только `Данная функция не генерирует криптографически безопасные значения и не должна использоваться в криптографических целях` - что картину отражает мало.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр Вы правы. Дополнил ответ